# Can't export XCode iPA from XCode organizer since yosemite upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, osx-yosemite

Ever since upgrading to Yosemite I can't complete the exportation of my build archive from XCode.

I've tried deleting my APP ID from XCode and re-adding it but this is what happens:
[image]

Prior to this in XCode organiser I couldn't export either. This is what happens when I try to export now:

[image]

When I click add the button just blanks out. Yesterday it would try to log in but would just time out also.

I deleted the certificates from keychain access and downloaded again and re-added.

I've also re-added the provisioning profiles.

Still no luck. I can't test in testflight as I can't get past the export stage in XCode organiser. I'm sure this is some how connected to the reason my safari can't browse any websites too. This all happened after the yosemite update.

Would appreciate some solutions if anybody has experienced and solved this issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Asking here isn't a bad idea, but I would definitely contact Apple as well on this one, and report back here what they say.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this issue was caused by my VPN. As soon as I turned it off everything began to work again. I've been using this VPN service for years so I'm 100% sure that Yosemite being the new figure in the equation messed things up.

This should shed some light on the issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6606981